# wicket - table - dynamically inserting rows without complete refresh of the table

Tags: dynamic, datatable, wicket

I've been playing around with Wicket for some time now and in one of the latest requirements that I received specifies that I should display some data in a table, and I'm wondering what is the best solution in my case: DataTable, DataView, ... ?

What is my case?
The table should display new rows submitted from a form on the same page by the current user or another user also connected to the application without refreshing the entire table to reduce the amount of data transferred.

What's your point of view?

Comment: So you want your typical chat behavior? I would add a empty container at the bottom/top of your content and replace it with more content whenever needed.

Comment: somehow yes but the it should keep the features from a table such as sorting based on the header, and if the table is sorted, the line should be inserted at the appropriate position and finally, when a line is added, it should be able to append to javascript to highlight it temporarily